# Testing User Interaction with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, lettuce, js-test-driver

I can't get Lettuce / Splinter or JsTestDriver to run tests of user interaction with Backbone-generated DOM objects.  For example, at the [hello backbone tutorial](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/2.html), I want to simulate the user's click on the button labeled "Add list item", then verify that a `<li>` element of text "hello world1" has appeared.

**JsTestDriver:** I can get a reference to the button element and call `click()` on it, but then `document.getElementsByTagName("li")` fail (or return null?).

Johansen's excellent [book](http://cjohansen.no/) says that testing event handlers isn't properly a unit testing task.  So I tried my BDD (?) tools for Django:

**Lettuce / Splinter / Django:** The Splinter Browswer object can't see the text in the button, never mind get a reference to it or click it.  (It does handle these operations for elements created via HTML.)  Neither world.browser.is_text_present() nor find_by_id() work; passing a wait time to the former didn't help.

I would really prefer to avoid going straight to Selenium, and thought that these tools made that unnecessary.  So now what?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? I don't want to revive a zombie.

Answer (score 1):

While firing DOM events may technically not be "unit testing", it doesn't mean you can't use a unit testing framework to do it :) This is more of a case of definition.

Anyway, you can achieve what you want with e.g. JsTestDriver, but I would advise against doing it manually through e.g. `click()` (which likely does not do what you expect it to). I usually use jQuery to fire events, and this can safely be done with e.g. JsTestDriver. This should work even if you don't use jQuery in your production code.

Comment: Thx, but I don't entirely follow.  Are you suggesting that I get a reference to the target element with jQuery, then call click() on that?  Or that I make some more involved usage of the jQuery Event model to call the event?  I'll have to brush up on jQuery for the latter.  And yes, click() isn't behaving as I would expect.

Comment: Are you think of the jquery.simulate.js library, w/jQuery and QUnit?  Because I did get that to work.